# IE Data Scraping

Tags: excel, internet-explorer, vba

I am trying to copy and paste a value from a webpage to excel. Here is the html for the webpage

```
<span id="123" style="456">4991</span>
```

Using this info is there any way to write a vba code that copies and pastes '4991' to a cell in excel?

My current code is below:

```
Sub iepractice()

Dim ie As InternetExplorer
Set ie = New InternetExplorer
ie.Visible = True

ie.navigate "####"
Do While ie.Busy = True Or ie.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

ie.document.getelementById("123").Copy
Cells(1,1).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

End Sub
```

I know that the copy and paste command is wrong, but I have no idea how else to go about scraping that specific piece of data.

Comment: Try `Cells(1,1) = ie.document.getelementById("123").InnerText`

Comment: Wow that did the trick. Thanks daniel!